# Django meta permissions

Tags: django, django-models

I am adding custom permissions via use of 'meta' in the Django models. See below for a simple example.

Models.py

```
class Meta:
    permissions = (
        ("can_do_stuff", "Can do stuff"),
    )
```

This works great, I add the above code to a model and then make my migrations and then migrate them. The permission gets created and is available for use.

However, when i remove (or modify) that permission from the 'meta' section of my model and again `makemigrations`, `migrate` the permission (that was removed/modified) is not removed from the Django system.

This wouldn't be a problem if i had figured out my permissions system 100% but I have been fine tuning things as I learn and as a result the permissions list gets messy with 'legacy' permissions.

I am developing and releasing new versions to production use on a frequent basis, and the permissions are getting messy in production where i can't just wipe the DB like i could in dev.

Is there a recommended way of doing this?

I could delete the legacy permissions manually directly from the database (it seems to be just one entry i need to delete and it seems to not cause any problems). This seems like a bad way of doing it, subject to error, being forgotten etc.

Comment: Have you tried making some other modification to the model to make sure a new migration is created, and checked that the permission isn't removed here?. EDIT: I found a [closed issue](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/23256) on this, it looks like it has been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried migrating backward instead of forward?

> `<app_label> <migrationname>`: Brings the database schema to a state where the named migration is applied, but no later migrations in the same app are applied. This may involve unapplying migrations if you have previously migrated past the named migration. Use the name zero to unapply all migrations for an app.

My guess is that the `makemigrations` command scans a model's permissions meta, and produce a 'insert' SQL in Permission table for each missing permssion, it doesn't actually do two-way synchronization in the migration script.

But the migration script can revert the changes with a 'delete' statement for every 'insert'.

So try:

```
python manage.py migrate the_app the_migration_before_the_last
```

If this doesn't work either, submit a bug to Django project.